# Operating on Pandas dataframe based on index criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a pandas dataframe that I need to filter out data from based of data points being close to one and another, for example, if there's 5 data points one after the other I want to just keep the data row that has the lowest value in another column.

An example of what I would like to like to happen is below:

```
df_orig = 

0 2
1 5
2 7
3 3
13 3
14 4
19 1
26 4
27 2
28 8
```

```
df_wanted

0 2
13 3
19 1
27 2
```

The first column in the above example are the index and the second is just a column with some values. I would like to filter `df_orig` so only one row is kept per cluster of data indexes based on the lowest value in the column.

Hope that makes sense and any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'value': [2, 5, 7, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 8]
}
index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 13, 14, 19, 26, 27, 28]

df_orig = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

# Calculate difference between the current and previous index
df_orig['diff'] = df_orig.index.to_series().diff().fillna(999)

# Determine clusters
df_orig['group'] = (df_orig['diff'] > 1).cumsum()

# Sort by value within each group and drop duplicates keeping the first (smallest value)
df_wanted = df_orig.sort_values(['group', 'value']).drop_duplicates('group', keep='first').drop(['diff', 'group'], axis=1)

print(df_wanted)
```

[image]